# Adding translucency to bootstrap navigation bars and photos, and increasing font sizes

Tags: jquery, html, css, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've looked at many posts on StackOverflow and other websites, but I just can't seem to figure out how to make my navbar in bootstrap translucent. I don't want the words in the navbar to be translucent, but I want just the navbar to be. I also want to apply an opacity to the background picture. I also want to increase the size of the "My App" text without changing the size of the links.

Heres my code:

http://goo.gl/P8jpgG

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and copy the relevant parts of your code to the question.

Comment: BTW, there's no such thing as text-decoration:bold;, you'll want to use font-weight instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want navbar to be transparent just apply CSS to it.

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

If you use Bootstrap Scrollspy and you want active menu items to be transparent aswell, you need to apply CSS to those with.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

To change font size of My App text, you can change CSS of `navbar-brand` class like

```
.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know, CSS capacity of the parent element applies to all the child elements as well (and for a good reason, it would be useless if that is not the case).

As for your question, I think that what you are after is CSS background color opacity. This is something you can achieve using RGBA colors - [this](http://www.css3maker.com/css-3-rgba.html) is one of generators available to create backgrounds with desired opacity.

This is an example of RGBA background color:

```
background-color: rgba(215, 44, 44, 0.2);
background: rgba(215, 44, 44, 0.2);
color: rgba(215, 44, 44, 0.2);
```

On the other hand, if you want to put a background image with opacity, you could try the following approach:

```
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(image.jpg);
  opacity: 0.8;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```

Basically it's adding a pseudo-element with top left positioning. Although in this case, I'm not sure why wouldn't you generate a PNG file instead (in Photoshop for example) with transparency already set and then just use that image for the background.